# Zingchart call getimagedata api via java

Tags: javascript, java, wicket, zingchart

I try to export zingchart image to get it in base64 object in java.

I want to use the getimageapi like this in js :

```
function exportImgChart(idChart) {
zingchart.exec('idChart', 'getimagedata', {
    filetype: 'png',
    callback : function(imagedata) {
        console.log(imagedata);
        document.getElementById('output_image').src = imagedata;
    }
});}
```

But I don't know how to call it from java code ? I put my js function like this :

```
    public void getImageChart(AjaxRequestTarget target, String idChart) {

    String js = MessageFormat.format("exportImgChart({0});", //
            StringUtils.wrap(this.getMarkupId(), "'") //
            );

    target.appendJavaScript(js);
    
    //how to get image base 64 here ?

}
```

My java framework is Wicket

Thanks for your help !

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

`getImageChart(AjaxRequestTarget, String)` is called because of some Ajax call made from the browser to the server.

Then at the server-side you construct a String that **will** be sent to the browser with the response. `target.appendJavaScript(js);` doesn't send it immediately. It just says "'js' will be part of the response" but the response is flushed to the browser once `getImageChart()` and few more methods are fully executed.

You cannot have the base64 encoded image right after `target.appendJavaScript(js)`. To get the base64 data you need to make a new Ajax call to the server in your JavaScript function `exportImgChart()`. This new Ajax call will most probably call new callback method, e.g. `onBase64Image()` or whatever you name it.

For more information see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42612027/497381

Comment: Ok thanks it's difficult to understand cause I'm new with wicket. I'll try the linked soluce and Come back if I have some question !